# JQuery UI slider's doesn't work at 0?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, meteor

I am trying to create a slider with JQuery UI in my meteor app with possible values between 0 and 1 with step size of 0.001 and I don't want the slider to have a default value nor show the handle of the slider until the user decides on a value first.

```
Template.game_task.onCreated(()=>{
    if (!Session.get("sliderValue")){
        Session.setPersistent('sliderValue', -1)
    }

});

Template.game_task.onRendered(()=> {

    /////// the slider stuff //////
    this.$("#slider").slider({
        min: -0.0000,
        max: 1,
        step: 0.01,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            $('#slider > .ui-slider-handle').show();
            Session.setPersistent('sliderValue',ui.value)
        },
        change: function(event, ui) {
            //save value to collection
        }
    });

    if (Session.get("sliderValue") === -1){
        //if no value is set, then hide the handle
        $('#slider > .ui-slider-handle').hide();
    }

});

Template.game_task.helpers({
    getSliderValue(){
        const sliderValue = Session.get('sliderValue');
        if (sliderValue){
            console.log('slider value to be returned',sliderValue)
            return sliderValue;
        }
    },

});
```

and this is the HTML:

```
<div class='row'>
    <div id="slider" class="custom-handle"></div>
    <span id="min">0</span>
    <span class="quarter">0.25</span>
    <span class="quarter">0.5</span>
    <span class="quarter">0.75</span>
    <span id="max">1</span>
    <p class="contributionText">Your guess: {{getSliderValue}}</p>
</div>
```

However, the slider is giving a weird behavior at the lower limit (when I pull the slider towards 0). As I go to the 0, I get down to small values (i.e., 0.01, 0.016) and then the value I get is null (as per my `getSliderValue()` function in `{{getSliderValue}}`).

[image]

So I am never able to pick 0 .. this doesn't happen at the higher end though as I go to 1.

[image]

Also, if I change the minimum value to something other than 0, I get the correct behavior at the lower limit (but in my case, it has to be 0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in this code:

```
if (sliderValue){
  ...
}
```

As your value is `0` this condition won't be `true`. You should change it to this:

```
if (sliderValue != null){
  ...
}
```

Comment: Improvement: `if (sliderValue !== null && typeof sliderValue !== 'undefined')`

Comment: @Jankapunkt That's exactly what my code means :) If you'll look at it you'll see there is `!= null` and that equals your code.

Comment: Sry for confusion, I forgot, that for negative comparison you don't need strict typechecking. sliderValue != null is in this case sufficient.

Comment: That's true not only for negative comparision. For example, `a == null` will check `a` for either `null` or `undefined` :)